# Как заставить работать AJAX в IE9?

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

Здравствуйте!
Есть исправно работающий в современных браузерах скрипт:

```
var have_active_element = false;
var active_element;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ajax());

function getXmlHttp() {
    var ro;
    try {
        ro = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
   } catch (e) {
       try {
           ro = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       } catch (f) {
           ro = null;
       }
   }
   if (!ro && typeof(XMLHttpRequest) !== 'undefined') {
       ro = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
    return ro;
}

function ajax() {
    var xhr = getXmlHttp();
    xhr.open('POST', 'index.php');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            document.getElementById('main-content').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        } else if (xhr.status !== 200) {
            alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
        }
    };
    xhr.send('mode=ajax');
}

function prepare() {
    ajax();
}

function name_valid(current_element) {
    var value = current_element.value;
    if (value.search(/^[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*(\s[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*)?$/) !== -1) { //Сдаюсь, лучше не могу
        if(value.length < 30){
            send(value, 'name');
            current_element.setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly');
            have_active_element = false;
        } else {
            alert('Введено более 30 символов');
        }
    } else {
        alert('В имени допустимы только русские символы, без цифр');
        return false;
    }
}

function age_valid(current_element) {
    var value = current_element.value;
    if (value.search(/^\d+$/) !== -1) {
        if (value < 3 || value > 100) {
            alert('Некорректные данные');
        } else {
            if(value.length < 3){
                send(value, 'age');
                current_element.setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly');
                have_active_element = false;
            }
        }
    } else {
        alert('Недопустимые символы');
    }
}

function send(value, name) {
    var row_id = active_element.parentNode.parentNode.id;
    row_id = row_id.split('_');
    row_id = row_id[1];
    var data = name + '=' + value + '&mode=update&row_id=' + row_id;
    var xhr = getXmlHttp();
    xhr.open('POST', 'index.php');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            active_element.setAttribute('value', xhr.responseText);
            alert('Данные успешно обновлены');
        } else if (xhr.status !== 200) {
            alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
        }
    };
    xhr.send(data);
}

function save_city(value) {
    var row_id = active_element.parentNode.parentNode.id;
    row_id = row_id.split('_');
    row_id = row_id[1];
    var data = 'mode=update&row_id=' + row_id + '&city=' + value;
    xhr = getXmlHttp();
    xhr.open('POST', 'index.php');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            //do something
        } else if (xhr.status !== 200) {
            alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
        }
    };
    xhr.send(data);
}

function show_select(current_element){
    if(have_active_element){
        alert('Завершите редактирование предыдущего элемента');
        return;
    }
    var parent = current_element.parentElement;
    var select = generate_select(true);
    active_element = select;
    active_element_value = current_element.value;
    current_element.remove();
    parent.appendChild(select);
    have_active_element = true;
}

function hide_select(current_element, value, name){
    var parent = active_element.parentNode;
    var input = generate_input(name);
    save_city(value);
    current_element.remove();
    parent.appendChild(input);
    have_active_element = false;
    active_element='';
}

function generate_select(mode) {
    var select = document.createElement('select');
    select.setAttribute('name', 'city_id');
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.text = '   ';
    select.appendChild(option);
    if (mode) select.setAttribute('onChange', 'hide_select(this, this.options[selectedIndex].value, this.options[selectedIndex].text)');
    for (var i = 0; i < city_names.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.innerHTML = city_keys[i];
        option.setAttribute('value', city_names[i]);
        select.appendChild(option);
    }
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.text = 'Не выбрано';
    option.setAttribute('value', 'NULL');
    select.appendChild(option);
    return select;
}

function change_state(current_element){
    if(have_active_element){
        alert('Завершите редактирование предыдущего элемента');
        return;
    }
    current_element.removeAttribute('readonly');
    have_active_element = true;
    active_element = current_element;
}

function generate_input(value){
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('value', value);
    input.setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly');
    input.setAttribute('onclick', 'show_select(this)');
    return input;
}

function validate(element){
    console.log('invoked validate')
    var form = document.forms.add_user;
    var name = form[0].value;
    var age = form[1].value;
    var city_id = form[2].options[form[2].selectedIndex].value;
    var valid = true;
     if (name.search(/^[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*(\s[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]*)?$/u) != -1) {
        if(name.length > 30){
         alert('Введено более 30 символов');
         valid = false;
        }
    } else {
        alert('В имени допустимы только русские символы, без цифр');
        valid = false;
    }
    if (age.search(/^\d+$/) != -1 && valid) {
        if (age < 3 || age > 100) {
            valid = false;
            alert('Возраст не может быть меньше 3 и больше 100');
        } else {
            if(age.length < 3){
                valid = true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        alert('Недопустимые символы');
        valid = false;
    }
    if(valid){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Никак не могу заставить это работать хоть как-нибудь в браузере IE9.
Как вообще отлаживаются сайты на IE?
[Располагается хост по этому адресу](http://37.194.132.64/livemasters/index.php)

Comment: Что конкретно не работает?

Comment: Насколько я понял из панели отладки, не отправляются запросы

Comment: У вас очень много лишнего кода в вопросе. Постарайтесь локализовать проблему и привести код, достаточный для воспроизводства этой проблемы.